# How can we edit generated config file with my project specific parameters in Doxygen using command line?

Tags: command-line, doxygen, configuration-files, doxywizard

Here I have attached my batch file.Doxyfile_HV is my config file and in that I only need to change PROJECT_NUMBER. But this doesn't work for me.

```
 @echo off 
 setLocal enabledelayedexpansion

 ( type Doxyfile_HV & echo PROJECT_NUMBER=1.1.1 ) | doxygen.exe -

 doxygen Doxyfile_HV
 hhc "%CD%"\html\index.hhp"
```

Comment: The second call to doxygen i.e. `doxygen Doxyfile_HV` undoes again the first call, with the change of the `PROJECT_NUMBER`.

Comment: Thank you so much @albert. it worked for me.

Comment: OK, just accept my answer (as this gives the relevant information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either change the values in your `Doxyfile` or invoke doxygen with extra parameters as described in the manual in the paragraph [Can I configure doxygen from the command line?](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_cmdline):

> Can I configure doxygen from the command line?
>
> Not via command line options, but doxygen can read from stdin, so you
>   can pipe things through it. Here's an example how to override an
>   option in a configuration file from the command line (assuming a UNIX
>   like environment):
>
> ( cat Doxyfile ; echo "PROJECT_NUMBER=1.0" ) | doxygen -
>
> For Windows the following would do the same:
>
> ( type Doxyfile & echo PROJECT_NUMBER=1.0 ) | doxygen.exe -
>
> If multiple options with the same name are specified then doxygen will
>   use the last one. To append to an existing option you can use the +=
>   operator.

Comment: I am a newbie. I tried this solution but this doesn't work for me. will you please elaborate step by step. Suppose I have a config file named with doxyfile_new and I only need to change PROJECT_NUMBER not any other parameters.

Comment: Explain what you tried and show error messages you got.

Comment: In the quoted text of the answer you probably only have to substitute the `Doxyfile` with `doxyfile_new` (in the cat / type line depending on your OS) and use the right value for the `PROJECT_NUMBER`.

Comment: Here I have attached my batch file.Doxyfile_HV is my config file and in that I only need to change PROJECT_NUMBER. But this doesn't work for me.

     @echo off 
     setLocal enabledelayedexpansion

     ( type Doxyfile_HV & echo PROJECT_NUMBER=1.1.1 ) | doxygen.exe -
     doxygen Doxyfile_HV
     hhc "%CD%"\html\index.hhp"

Comment: Due to the comment format it is a bit hard to read, please paste the example into the original question. as far as I can see you call doxygen twice, but the one time is sufficient, but here it should, probably, not read `Doxyfile` but `Doxyfile_HV`. The `(type...)` does not change the `Doxyfile` but just feeds it to doxygen with just the `PROJECT_NUMBER` changed.

Comment: I have edited my original question, please go through that